# How to obtain cmip6 projected temperature data?

Tags: data-request, climate, meteorology

I would like to get projected temperature data under various climate scenarios till 2100 for different European countries.

I find CMIP5 data under four RCPs in world bank, I am also interested in the new scenarios of CMIP6 but I am not sure that there are available.